# MongoDB Rust: Projections with typed collections | How to do this?

Tags: mongodb, rust, graphql

I am pretty new to Rust and just trying to learn it while coding a GraphQL API using MongoDB. Currently, I am struggling with decoding a document into my `CourseDocument` struct.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Eq)]
struct CourseDocument {
    #[serde(rename = "_id")]
    id: ObjectId,
    #[serde(rename = "localizedFields")]
    localized_fields: Vec<CourseDocumentLocalizedFields>,
    categories: Vec<ObjectId>,
    tags: Vec<ObjectId>,
    trainers: Vec<ObjectId>,
    videos: Vec<ObjectId>,
}

impl PartialEq for CourseDocument {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.id == other.id
    }
}
```

In my `main()` function I tried the following

```
let course_collection = database.collection::<CourseDocument>("courses");

let projection = doc! {"localizedFields": 1};

let options = FindOptions::builder()
    .limit(10)
    .projection(projection)
    .build();

let mut cursor = course_collection.find(None, options).await.unwrap();

while let Some(course) = cursor.try_next().await.unwrap() {
    println!("{:#?}", course)
}
```

This code throws the following error:
`Error { kind: InvalidResponse { message: "missing field 'categories'" }, labels: {} }`

The error does make sense because the `CourseDocument` requires the `categories` field to be at least an empty vector. But I am still wondering what would be the correct `struct` declaration.

Do I have to wrap every field with an `Option` enum to make projections and typed documents possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`clone_with_type()`](https://docs.rs/mongodb/latest/mongodb/struct.Collection.html#method.clone_with_type) to make a `Collection` with the same source but with a different type. Using that, you can deserialize into a type with only those projected fields.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct ProjectedCourseDocument {
    #[serde(rename = "localizedFields")]
    localized_fields: Vec<CourseDocumentLocalizedFields>,
}
```

```
let mut cursor = course_collection
    .clone_with_type::<ProjectedCourseDocument>()
    .find(None, options)
    .await
    .unwrap();
```

Comment: do I have to do this for every possible projection then or is there a nicer way to handle this? I have searched everywhere but did not find a nice solution yet.

Comment: I don't have a better suggestion if you want the results to be well-typed. Are you projecting only what fields are queried by GraphQL? You could do what you originally suggested and make all the fields optional.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I thought there would be a nice way to achieve this.